# Make thread-safe a normal class with ThreadLocal<T>

Tags: c#, properties, thread-safety, thread-local

I have a normal class designed to be accessed by a single thread and I want to make it `thread-safe` so many threads can use a single instance at the same time. There are some class level methods and variables which I will make static and using `locks` make them `thread-safe`. Also methods which **only** use local variables are safe (each thread has it's stack) by default.

My question it about `properties` of the old class or more generally any `non-static` variable. Can I simply use `ThreadLocal<T>` and each thread has it's own set of `properties` ? Surely I will use `locks` and other `thread-safety` issues inside `setters` (I assume `getters` are safe).

And is `ThreadLocal<T>` performance killer ?

Comment: Without describing what this class does, and why there would be interference from multiple threads, nobody can give you a good answer.

Comment: What precisely do you believe that ThreadLocal does?  Because I do not think it does what you think it does. Can you explain why you think that thread local storage is the correct solution?

Comment: @Eric: I read it makes a variable local to a thread. So we have as many properties as number of running threads. So the object can have state per thread.

Comment: Right: it makes state per thread. So suppose you have an object Customer with a property Name, accessed from two different threads. Is your idea of how to make the Customer object "thread safe" to have the customer have two different names, depending on which thread does the asking?  Thread local storage is almost *never* what you want when making an object threadsafe, so I just want to make sure that you are barking up the right tree here.

Comment: Data belong to threads. I mean the class works like a service provider to threads but it's methods should use data for the same thread to function properly (the running thread would get right answer based on it's own data).

Comment: Then it sounds like you are looking at the right thing. However, I am concerned about your comment that locks need to go on setters but not getters. That doesn't make any sense. What if a getter runs while a setter is halfway through setting the property? If you're going to use locks it only makes sense to *always* use them.

Comment: As for the performance question: You are the only one who can answer it. Write some benchmarks and measure the performance under realistic situations, and see if that performance is acceptable to your users. We don't know what hardware you're using, how much memory you are consuming, or whether your customers want code that gives the right answer in two minutes or two microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Getters are not as safe as you think. The Java memory model gives each thread it's own view of the heap, so if you don't synchronize access to variables then threads may read stale data. Making a variable `volatile` will prevent stale reads and is fine for primitives, but `volatile` won't make access atomic.

There are a bunch of classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package that might help you out. Writing thread-safe code is tricky, so I'd recommend getting a good book on the subject. Brian Goetz's "Java concurrency in practice" is pretty good.

Comment: somebody added Java to question tags (edited). This is a C# class.

Comment: Ah. Well, if you ever do anything in Java then bear the memory thing in mind.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really what thread locals are for. They're intended for cases where each thread will have its own data.

In your case, I would suggest changing the field type to `Map<Object, Object>` and using [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) to to make it thread safe.

Comment: somebody added `Java` to question tags (edited). This is a `C#` class.